# Representatives of normal subgroups and intersections

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $U, V$ and $H$ be finite index subgroups of a group $G$ with $U$ and $V$ normal in $G$. Is there a way to relate representatives of $U/V$ with representatives of $H\cap U/H\cap V$?

Specifically, we are trying to relate the following formal sums:

$$\sum_{x_i \in U/V} x_i$$
$$\sum_{y_i \in H\cap U/H \cap V} y_i$$
in a way that rewrites the $y_i$ in terms of the $x_i$ or vice-versa.

Comment: You could choose a list of  coset representatives $y_1,\ldots,y_k$ of $H \cap V$ in $H \cap U$ and then extend that to a list $y_1,\ldots,y_k,x_{k+1},\ldots, x_n$ of coset representatives of $V$ in $U$.